# Is it possible to add custom field to JSON by condition in Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, laravel-query-builder

genius guys.

I am making Instagram like website by Laravel.
People can post picture, push 'love' button as we can do on Instagram.

My question is how to implement whether current login user is pushed 'love' or not.

I finally managed to get the list of which user pushed 'love' as below in this controller. But it is too much useless information. What if 1k people pushed 'love'... it gonna be terrible JSON.

I already killed a whole day for to make this part... Hope I can get your help. Thanks.

**Current JSON structure.**
[image: current Json structure]
**Current Code.**
[image: Current Code]
**Comment model.**
[image: Comment model]

Comment: I don't see the need to show two images of the same code.  I think it clutters the question.  You could just explain that you wanted to delete the code highlighted in yellow after the first image, and replace it with something that generates loved:true or loved:false.

Comment: Also, you should paste in the code rather than providing screenshots. This makes it easier for people to reproduce etc.. You can easily highlight the relevant part with comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attributes and appends to create a custom data field. Since it's a boolean, I'm going to call it `is_loved`, but you can change it if you like.

```php
class Comment extends Model
{
    // attributes to append to JSON response
    protected $appends = ['is_loved'];

    // ... your other properties and methods

    public function getIsLovedAttribute()
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            return !! $this->loveComments()->where('from',auth()->user()->id)->count();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now there is no longer any need to load the `love_comments` relationship.

EDIT: I added an authorization check to make sure the user is logged in first.  This is in case you show comments publicly to guests.  Otherwise, it could throw an error.

Comment: I want to pass params to getIsLovedAttribute(), so I changed it to getIsLovedAttribute($userID). Now I put "$query->getIsLovedAttribute($userID);" within "$query->with(array('comments'...." but I got error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany:' it seems laravel take it as hasMany relationship. What is the proper way to call this function?

Comment: I realized it is not possible to pass parm to accessor. thanks anyway!

Comment: In your original question, you wrote `all I want is current login user`, correct?  This is exactly what `auth()->user()` provides, where then `auth()->user()->id` is the logged in user's id.  Is this not what you were looking for?  Happy to provide any other insight if you are trying to work out another use case.

Comment: In order to  do this, I am gonna move authProvider from javascript to php.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I just assumed since you were using Laravel that it was already handling your authorizations.  Hopefully not too much work to change over.

Comment: I use firebase auth. haha Javascript is handling authorizations. Thanks anyway!